# Customize OOTB Table of Content Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using OOTB Table Of Content web part. However, the structure that it displays slightly differs from the one I need to show. I need to hide several node + render some additional. I though that I could take advantage of the control that is used that Table Of Content web part (if there's one). Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Content Query Web Part or you can create a new web part using OOTB toc web part as a base and render it on your own. You can do additional operations that way as well.